# EditForm Header-Detail in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, invoice, blazor-editform

I'm new to Blazor (Server). I see EditForm is very useful for CRUD and validation for a single model instance. However, when implementing a Header-Detail form (such as an invoice with an editable inner item list), I can't understand which model to assign to the EditContext of the EditForm. That is, I have the header model and a list of model instances (table) for the related items.
Is the EditForm not practical for that kind of form? Is there another options in Blazor?

Comment: I would display the child items in a grid or table with edit buttons that route to an editor component with it's own form, model and validation. Same component could be used for Add.

Comment: I prefer inline editing, but I will evaluate your suggestion. Thank you, Steve.

Comment: Check out the [Blazorise grid](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/) in that case.